# Cocos2d 2.x: enabling z-buffering and using vertexz

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, buffering, zbuffer

**Assumption:** I am using Cocos2D 2.0 that uses OpenGL 2.0 ES.

My game has **one spritesheet for all level assets** (e.g. background, enemies, clouds) and one for the player character sprites and HUD elements (e.g. usually both at a z-level above the rest of the assets). This is due to the fact that I allow the user to change player sprite and couldn't [fit all assets](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/#more-3365) in one spritesheet.

I am also using CCSpriteBatchNode for the two sprite sheets and pvr.ccz compressed texture files. **The issue is that, under some circumnstances, I'd need to change the absolute z-level of some assets** (eg. clouds, player, boss position) **which are in different sprite sheets** (level spritesheet, player spritesheet).

Two practical case scenario:

- **one**: I would like the player to go below the clouds, hence dynamically change the absolute z position of the player's sprite also in respect to the level assets sprite batch node.
- **two**: When the level boss arrives I would like to get the boss to fly above the player (hence absolute z-level should be +1 compared to the player sprite z-level). This also seem to require enabling z-buffering and using vertexz.

Now, I am confused on **how to do this** because as far as I know each sprite sheet is considered as a different node and hence a different OpenGL call (**would enabling z-buffering and vertexz decrease my performance requiring more calls?)**, and was wondering if there are some **tuturials/references** out there that might help me and/or **if someone could please share some experience for a similar case scenario**.

Comment: it doesn't cause more draw calls due to the z-buffer, but the depth test costs some performance.